# convert latest date to convert into time_ago format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I have the following code that returns me the latest date:

```
my_dates = due_dates.results.map { |result| result.date_value}
= my_dates.max
// returns 2012-07-25T00:00:00+00:00
```

I want the date to be returned in time ago format:

```
time_ago_in_words(my_dates))
```

since the max method changes the format the time_ago does not work.

Note my_dates returns

```
[Wed, 25 Jul 2012 00:00:00 +0000, Wed, 25 Jul 2012 00:00:00 +0000]
```

I am not sure how to go about to achieve the result in time_ago format.

Comment: You have to use time_ago_in_words in your view as it's a helper from ActionView or include ActionView helpers in your controller with `include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelpers`. Regards.

Comment: how do you store the dates in your database? are you using ÀctiveSupport`? how can it happen, that the `Enumerable#max`-Method should change your result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using time values for dates. Why not just use `DateTime.to_date` [(docs)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-to_date) and then compare dates?
2. Next, the [Enumerable#max](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) method compares elements on their `<=>`-method. It doesn't change type or value.

Maybe this helps you out:

```
max = [Time.now, Time.now-2.hours].max                # => 2013-07-08 19:05:35 +0200
max = [Time.now, Time.now-2.hours].map(&:to_date).max # => Mon, 08 Jul 2013
ActionView::DateHelpers.time_ago_in_words(max)        # => "about 10 minutes ago"
```

Comment: what exactly did help you - maybe you could make your question more generic so when somebody has the same question, we can give him / her the chance to get an answer as well.